# How can I use variables in crontab command

Tags: python, django, cron

I am trying to pass a variable as a command to crontab file through a python script with the help of os.system().

`selvalue = postedinfo['selvalue']
hours = postedinfo['hours']
minutes = postedinfo['minutes']`

The content of the variables are of string type inputed from django web app UI

`mycommand =" ".join([str(minutes),str(hours),'*','*',str(day),'python','/home/sat034/WorkSpace/NetworkInventory/manage.py','periodic_tasks'])`

I want to pass this command to os.system()

output = os.system("(crontab -l ; echo mycommand) 2>&1 | grep -v 'no crontab' | sort - | uniq - | crontab -")

But I am getting an error when I execute this:

`"-":2: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.`

If I replace mycommand variable with complete string it is working fine.

What is the problem with mycommand variable.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Got the solution for the above.

I have forgot to use join

cmd = "".join(["(crontab -l ; echo ",mycommand,") 2>&1 | grep -v 'no crontab' | sort - | uniq - | crontab -"])

output = os.system(cmd)

After this again I am getting the following error:

"-":1: bad day-of-month
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Comment: The contents of the variables are?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, variables are string type taken from django web app UI

Comment: That's nice. What are their contents?